# Stardog DB connection with Java

Tags: java, database, connection, stardog

I'm trying to do something really simple: will connect to the DB, read some records, and display them in a nice interface.

So far all I've done is start and stop the server, using the following code:

```
Server aServer = Stardog
                .buildServer()
                .bind(SNARLProtocolConstants.EMBEDDED_ADDRESS)
                .start();
```

To operate this, I had to download and import [SLF4J](http://slf4j.org/download.html), and also import all libraries found in my `stardog / server`.

Then I could start and stop the server, but my problem is I can not connect to my database.

I am using the following code to try to connect:

```
try (Connection aConn = ConnectionConfiguration
                .to("myDB")
                .credentials("admin", "admin")
                .connect())
        {
            aConn.begin();
            ...
            ...
        }
```

I affirm that I am sure that my credential data and database name are correct.

That `try`, going straight `finally`, `catch` bypasses.

In addition I can say, I was leading me by the [link below](https://gist.github.com/mhgrove/1045573). I'm coding in Eclipse 4.5.2, and using Java 1.8.

What am I doing wrong?. Thank you.

Comment: Strangely the connection string that worked for me was: `connection = ConnectionConfiguration.from("snarl://localhost:5820/myDB").credentials("admin", "admin").connect();` Note that the name of the DB is integrated into the server address. The address of the server mentioned as an example, is the local address used by default. It may be useful for someone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the only jars you've included in the classpath are what's in `stardog / server`, then the likely cause is that you're missing some required dependencies.

Probably, either the contents of `client/http` and/or `client/snarl`.

But really, you shouldn't be managing that manually, [use Gradle or Maven](http://docs.stardog.com/#_using_maven).

Comment: I followed your instructions. I added completely client and server folders. Thus it worked perfectly.

I'm working on Eclipse. It was not easy to make it work Maven, so I chose to add the libraries manually.

Thanks for your help!.